# Splitting elements of list into an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I have a data set of strings and i need to filter out the key parts of string into an array.

`data[0]`
gives output:

```
['<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="8.0" fill="silver" rx="16.0" ry="16.0" /',
 '<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="56.0" fill="green" rx="32.0" ry="16.0" /',
 '<ellipse cx="8.0" cy="8.0" fill="green" rx="16.0" ry="32.0" /']
```

What i need to create is the following array:

`key_data[0] -> [['ellipse' , 32.0, 8.0, 'silver', 16.0, 16.0], [ 'ellipse', 32.0, 56.0, 'green', 32.0, 16.0], ['ellipse', 8.0, 8.0, 'green', 16.0, 32.0]]`

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Looks like a simple regular expression should be able to extract all the bits that you want.

Comment: Shouldn't there ba a `'` at the end of the third ellipse in the input?

Comment: @Barmar, yes will edit this

Comment: is 'ellipse' always there? or can it be different data? If so, please provide a generalised model... Like @Barmar said:  a simple [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) will probably do the job. check out [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to interactively build and test your own. It's my go-to editor for regex building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

data = ['<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="8.0" fill="silver" rx="16.0" ry="16.0" /',
        '<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="56.0" fill="green" rx="32.0" ry="16.0" /',
        '<ellipse cx="8.0" cy="8.0" fill="green" rx="16.0" ry="32.0" /']

re_compile = re.compile(r'<(.*?) cx="(.*?)" cy="(.*?)" fill="(.*?)" rx="(.*?)" ry="(.*?)" /')
result = list(map(lambda x: re_compile.search(x).groups(), data))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using regex. `re.match`.

**Ex:**

```
import re

data = ['<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="8.0" fill="silver" rx="16.0" ry="16.0" /', '<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="56.0" fill="green" rx="32.0" ry="16.0" /', '<ellipse cx="8.0" cy="8.0" fill="green" rx="16.0" ry="32.0" /']
result = []
for i in data:
    m = re.match(r"\<([a-z]+) \w+=(.*?)\s\w+=(.*?)\s\w+=(.*?)\s\w+=(.*?)\s\w+=(.*?)", i)
    result.append([j.strip('"') for j in m.groups() if j])
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['ellipse', '32.0', '8.0', 'silver', '16.0'],
 ['ellipse', '32.0', '56.0', 'green', '32.0'],
 ['ellipse', '8.0', '8.0', 'green', '16.0']]
```

---

or using `re.match` & `re.findall`

**Ex:**

```
data = ['<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="8.0" fill="silver" rx="16.0" ry="16.0" /', '<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="56.0" fill="green" rx="32.0" ry="16.0" /', '<ellipse cx="8.0" cy="8.0" fill="green" rx="16.0" ry="32.0" /']
result = []
for i in data:
    m = re.match(r"\<([a-z]+)", i)
    attribs = re.findall(r'\w+="(.*?)"', i)
    result.append([m.group(1)] + attribs )
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` is a better approach, but if you don't want to use it, you can do in this way:

```
new_l = []
for i in data:
    sub_l = []
    el = i.split()
    sub_l.append(el[0][1:])
    for e in el[1:]:
        x = e.split('=')
        try:
            sub_l.append(x[1].strip().strip('"'))
        except IndexError:
            continue
    new_l.append(sub_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't make use of regular expressions.

```py
a = ['<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="8.0" fill="silver" rx="16.0" ry="16.0" ',
 '<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="56.0" fill="green" rx="32.0" ry="16.0" ',
 '<ellipse cx="8.0" cy="8.0" fill="green" rx="16.0" ry="32.0" ']

d = [i.split() for i in a]
r = [[j.split('=')[-1] for j in i] for i in d]
s = [[i.strip('"').lstrip('<') for i in k] for k in r]

# convert to float where possible
for k in s:
    for i, j in enumerate(k):
        try:
            k[i] = float(j)
        except ValueError:
            pass

>>> print(s)
[['ellipse', 32.0, 8.0, 'silver', 16.0, 16.0],
['ellipse', 32.0, 56.0, 'green', 32.0, 16.0],
['ellipse', 8.0, 8.0, 'green', 16.0, 32.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable using regular expression you can use this bit of code.

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

def return_list(ellipse_list):
    final_res = []
    for ellipse in ellipse_list:
        res = [literal_eval(item.split("=")[1]) if "=" in item else item for item in ellipse[1:-1].split(" ")[:-1]]
        final_res.append(res)

`return final_res`

Answer (score 0):

The content of the list looks like XML and XML should be treated as XML. There is just a final `'>'` missing. So we can use an XML parser to handle this.

```
from lxml import etree

data = ['<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="8.0" fill="silver" rx="16.0" ry="16.0" /',
        '<ellipse cx="32.0" cy="56.0" fill="green" rx="32.0" ry="16.0" /',
        '<ellipse cx="8.0" cy="8.0" fill="green" rx="16.0" ry="32.0" /']


def parse_element(element):
    # adjust faulty XML if needed
    if not element.rstrip().endswith('>'):
        element += '>'

    # create the XML structure
    doc = etree.XML(element)

    # gather all attribute values in a dictionary
    attributes = ['cx', 'cy', 'rx', 'ry', 'fill']
    values = {attribute_name: doc.get(attribute_name) for attribute_name in attributes}

    # construct target
    entry = [doc.tag,
             float(values['cx']),
             float(values['cy']),
             values['fill'],
             float(values['rx']),
             float(values['ry'])]

    return entry


result = [parse_element(element) for element in data]
print(result)
```

If the order of the attributes changes this will still run.